# multilingual language site (Drupal) entity reference

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, forms

I am working on multilingual language site (Drupal) I would like to get data depends on language can I know how to write query using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) ?

Comment: Please include "something" (PHP, SQL, ...) to illustrate what you have tried so far, and what kind of problems you encountered in doing so. Maybe also describe what kind of SQL query you want to execute ...

Comment: More info please